# AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'correlation_tracker'

Tags: python, dlib

I have installed dlib 19.17 version. When it running suddenly it stops and is showing the error:

```
"AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'correlation_tracker'"
```

---

```
import dlib
tracker = dlib.correlation_tracker()
```

Comment: Are you running this using a script or in the interactive interpreter?

Comment: I faced the same issue once I had to uninstall and install it again because of wrong version.
`pip uninstall dlib`
`pip install dlib`

This may help you.

Comment: pip install is not worked for me I am using cmake to build @DimoMohit

Comment: I am using visual studio code IDE for this @Flying even it is not working for python cmd also

Comment: Did you make sure that you ran `python setup.py` with the same interpreter that visual studio code is using, that your working directory is outside of the source directory and that you don't have a script that is called `dlib.py`?